# How to display resulting image of mainwindow in another window in C++ and QT?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

I am currently working on Qt creator. I want to just get an image by browsing from hard drive in mainwindow and then after converting the RGB color image to gray image, I want to display the gray image in the another window.

By clicking the button "Browse", color image can be loaded where color to gray image conversion will be applied. Here `grayImage` is a public Mat type variable. At the same time an instance of another window named `SecondDialog` will be called to be executed.

```
void MainWindow::on_Browse_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Images"), "/home/rpi/Desktop/Picture/Sample Pictures", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        String image_path=fileName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        Mat image= imread(image_path);
        cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        SecondDialog obj;
        obj.setModal(true);
        obj.exec();
    }
}
```

In the seconddialog.cpp, I have converted the Mat image to QImage to display on a QLabel named `label_img`

```
SecondDialog::SecondDialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::SecondDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    
    MainWindow object;
    Mat src= object.grayImage;
    Mat temp(src.cols,src.rows,src.type());
    QImage dest((const uchar *) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    dest.bits();
    ui->label_img->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(dest));
}
SecondDialog::~SecondDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

When I run this program, there is no compilation error, but it is now displaying any image in the second window.
I am not able to figure out if there is any mistake in my code. It would be really helpful if anyone could fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have just tried according to your solution. But it is still not displaying.

Comment: I have just added this in my github account. The programs can be found in the following link github.com/ashraful100/DisplayImage Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are creating a new object of type MainWindow:

```
[...]
ui(new Ui::SecondDialog)
{
ui->setupUi(this);    
MainWindow object;
[...]
```

And this has the empty `grayImage` attribute so you get this behavior.

another problem is the format you use, you must change from `QImage::Format_RGB888` to `QImage::Format_Indexed8`.

> Format_RGB888: The image is stored using a 24-bit RGB format (8-8-8).
>
> Format_Indexed8: The image is stored using 8-bit indexes into a colormap.

What you have to do is create a setter method and pass the image to the new window for it you must do the following:

**SecondDialog.h**

```
public:
    void setImage(const Mat &image);
```

**SecondDialog.cpp**

```
SecondDialog::SecondDialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::SecondDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    
}

void SecondDialog::setImage(const Mat &image){
    QImage dest((const uchar *) image.data, image.cols, image.rows, image.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    ui->label_img->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(dest));
}
```

So in the end you should run the following in MainWindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_Browse_clicked()
{

    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Images"), "/home/rpi/Desktop/Picture/Sample Pictures", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        String image_path=fileName.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        Mat image= imread(image_path);
        cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        SecondDialog obj;
        obj.setImage(grayImage);
        obj.setModal(true);
        obj.exec();
    }

}
```

Edit:

In my case I use the following function to do the conversion of `cv::Mat` to `QImage`:

```
# https://github.com/eyllanesc/Mirosot-Peru/blob/master/Mirosot-PC/MatToQImage.cpp
QImage MatToQImage(const cv::Mat& mat)
{
    // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=1
    if(mat.type()==CV_8UC1)
    {
        // Set the color table (used to translate colour indexes to qRgb values)
        QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
            colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i,i,i));
        // Copy input Mat
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
        // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        img.setColorTable(colorTable);
        return img;
    }
    // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=3
    if(mat.type()==CV_8UC3)
    {
        // Copy input Mat
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
        // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        return img.rgbSwapped();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: Mat could not be converted to QImage.";
        return QImage();
    }
} // MatToQImage()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried with this edits also. But unfortunately, it is still not displaying the grayImage. Can you explain why MainWindow had an empty grayImage?

Comment: You could share your project to be able to help and give you a completely tested response through drive, dropbox, github or similar.

Comment: I have just added this in my github account. The programs can be found in the following link https://github.com/ashraful100/DisplayImage
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Ohh really, it is now working fine. Cordially thanks for your immediate assistance.

Comment: @Gansroy If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct please.